# Gradle maven-publish for Spring-Boot project throws error: Cannot find parent: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent for project

Tags: gradle, spring-boot

I am new to Gradle so any help with this error will be highly appreciated.

I am building a REST based service using Spring-boot. I want to publish the JAR file to the local maven repository so that my web application can use it. After trying many things, I finally settled for maven-publish plugin. Here is my build.gradle file

```
//Needed for spring-boot
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.1.8.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'eclipse'

// Apply the groovy plugin to add support for Groovy
apply plugin: 'groovy'

//apply Spring-boot plugin
apply plugin: 'spring-boot'

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

// In this section you declare where to find the dependencies of your project
repositories {
    mavenLocal()

    // Use 'jcenter' for resolving your dependencies.
    // You can declare any Maven/Ivy/file repository here.
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

group = "com.proto"

publishing {
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId "${project.group}"
            artifactId "${project.name}"
            version "${project.jar.version}"
            artifact sourceJar { classifier "sources" }
            from components.java

            pom.withXml {
                asNode().appendNode('parent')
                        .appendNode('groupId', 'org.springframework.boot').parent()
                        .appendNode('artifactId', 'spring-boot-starter-parent').parent()
                        .appendNode('version', '1.1.8.RELEASE')

                asNode().appendNode('repositories').appendNode('repository')
                        .appendNode('id', 'spring-releases').parent()
                        .appendNode('url', 'http://repo.spring.io/libs-release')
            }
        }
    }
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) { 
    from sourceSets.main.allJava 
}

jar {
    baseName = 'my-api'
    version =  '0.0.1'
}

task('execJar', type:Jar, dependsOn: 'jar') {
    baseName = 'my-api'
    version =  '0.0.1'
    classifier = 'exec'
    from sourceSets.main.output
}

bootRepackage  {
    withJarTask = tasks['execJar']
}

// In this section you declare the dependencies for your production and test code
dependencies {
    // We use the latest groovy 2.x version for building this library
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.6'

    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1'

    // tag::jetty[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") 
//  {
//  exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
//  }
//  compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jetty")
//  end::jetty[]

    // tag::actuator[]
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")

    // We use the awesome Spock testing and specification framework
    testCompile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.11'
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('cglib:cglib:3.1')
}

// tag::wrapper[]
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.1'
}
```

My problem is that, when I run:

```
gradle publishToMavenLocal
```

I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':publishMavenPublicationToMavenLocal'.
> Failed to publish publication 'maven' to repository 'MavenLocal'
   > Unable to initialize POM pom-default.xml: Cannot find parent: org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent for project: com.proto:proto-api:jar:0.0.1 for project com.proto:proto-api:jar:0.0.1
```

My gradle environment details:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2014-09-08 10:40:39 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     e6cf70745ac11fa943e19294d19a2c527a669a53

Groovy:       2.3.6
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.7.0_72 (Oracle Corporation 24.72-b04)
OS:           Linux 3.13.0-39-generic amd64
```

What am I missing?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have fixed the issue.
I am behind our corporate firewall, and had configured proxy correctly for gradle in ~/.gradle/gradle.properties file. But, I missed setting proxies for maven in ~/.m2/settings.xml file.

I configured our internal nexus repository to handle this issue but setting **proxies** block should work as well. [Click here for maven settings.xml documentation](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies)

Answer (score 1):

Same as @aardee, I am sitting behind our corporate firewall but it seems that my proxy settings (settings.xml) for maven local did not change anything. Fortunately we have our own maven repository that can proxy out and so I just replaced the repository in the generated pom and made sure that our company maven repository knows the relevant spring repos.

```
pom.withXml {
            asNode().appendNode('parent')
                    .appendNode('groupId', 'org.springframework.boot').parent()
                    .appendNode('artifactId', 'spring-boot-starter-parent').parent()
                    .appendNode('version', '1.1.8.RELEASE')

            asNode().appendNode('repositories').appendNode('repository')
                    .appendNode('id', 'spring-releases').parent()
                    .appendNode('url', 'http://my.mavenRepo.com/releases}
```

Replace http://my.mavenRepo.com/releases with your own maven repository.